# Calling a JavaScript Function Alters the Value of a Parameter. Why?

Tags: javascript

I'm having a little trouble with JavaScript. When I call the function compare in 'LINE 2' below it changes the value of to_sort[i] but not the pivot. The value being printed at 'LINE 1' is different from 'LINE 3'. Why is this?

I thought that this may have something to do with pivot and to_sort[i] being passed by reference but apparently primitive types are passed by value in JavaScript.

Help appreciated.

```
function compare(str1, str2){
    for (i = 0;i < Math.min(str1.length,str2.length); ++i){
        if(str2[i] < str1[i]){
            return false;
        }
    }
    if(str1.length != str2.length && str2.length < str1.length){
        return false;   
    }
    return true;

}

function quicksort(to_sort){
    if(to_sort.length < 2) return to_sort;
    var pivot = to_sort[0];
    var less_pivot = [];
    var more_pivot = [];
    for(i = 1; i < to_sort.length; ++i){
        console.log(to_sort[i]);// LINE 1
        if(compare(to_sort[i], pivot)){//LINE 2
            console.log(to_sort[i]); //LINE 3
            less_pivot = less_pivot.concat(to_sort[i]);
        }
        else{
            more_pivot = more_pivot.concat(to_sort[i]);
        }
    }
    return [].concat(quicksort(less_pivot, compare_function), pivot, quicksort(more_pivot, compare_function));
}
quicksort(["2.0.1", "2.0.0"]);

output:
2.0.0
undefined
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like it happens because `compare` function changes the value of the iteration index `i`:

```
for (i = 0; i < Math.min(str1.length, str2.length); ++i) {
    if (str2[i] < str1[i]) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

because you declare `i` without `var` keyword. Remember that assignment to undeclared variable results into global variable.

Comment: I'm very new to JavaScript and actually didn't know that and am glad I now do. Thanks.